# Fixing my basic Lua battle system

Tags: debugging, lua

This is a problem that I cannot seem to fix. I am a very new programmer and I love to code, however, I need help with this extremely basic battle system that I'm sure all you won't mind giving me. It isn't good looking or clean, so any tips on how I could shorten my code will also be greatly appreciated.

```
local function battle() -- All of this is 100% unfinished, by the way
  n = math.random(10) + 1 -- Everybody's HP, enemy HP randomly generated number from 10 to 100
  enemyhp = 10*n
  herohp = 100
  io.write("Your HP: ")
  io.write(herohp)
  io.write(" ")
  io.flush()
  io.write("Enemy HP: ")
  io.write(enemyhp)
  io.write(" ")
  io.flush()
  if enemyhp <= 0 then
  print("You won!")
end
local function attack()  -- Attacking the enemy or running away
  print("|Attack|Flee|")
  input = io.read()
  if input = "attack" then -- This is where my error is
    attackdamage = math.random(51)
    if attackdamage = 51 then
      print("Critical Hit!")
      enemyhp - 100
    else
      enemyhp - attackdamage
      print("Enemy took ")
      io.write(attackdamage)
      io.write(" damage!")
  elseif input = "flee" then
    print("You ran away!")
    end
  end
end
```

Thank you.

Comment: `math.random(10)` generates a random number between 1 and 10, inclusive, so if you add one you'll get a number that can be either 2 or 11 or one of the number in the middle. This way the enemy's hp will be a number between 110 and 20.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the end of your `if` block. It should be

```
if enemyhp <= 0 then
  print("You won!")
end
```

Second problem is the line you point to: You need to compare using two equal signs (`==`) instead of one:

```
if input == "attack" then
```

Then when you assign value to some variable, you need to use one equal sign. Otherwise it is just expression with no meaning.

```
enemyhp = enemyhp - 100
```

and then the same errors repeat (you have one additional `end` in the end too). Full code, you can compile/run: http://ideone.com/dgPoZo

```
local function battle() -- All of this is 100% unfinished, by the way
  n = math.random(10) + 1 -- Everybody's HP, enemy HP randomly generated number from 10 to 100
  enemyhp = 10*n
  herohp = 100
  io.write("Your HP: ")
  io.write(herohp)
  io.write(" ")
  io.flush()
  io.write("Enemy HP: ")
  io.write(enemyhp)
  io.write(" ")
  io.flush()
  if enemyhp <= 0 then
    print("You won!")
  end
end
local function attack()  -- Attacking the enemy or running away
  print("|Attack|Flee|")
  input = io.read()
  if input == "attack" then -- This is where my error is
    attackdamage = math.random(51)
    if attackdamage == 51 then
      print("Critical Hit!")
      enemyhp = enemyhp - 100
    else
      enemyhp = enemyhp - attackdamage
      print("Enemy took ")
      io.write(attackdamage)
      io.write(" damage!")
    end
  elseif input == "flee" then
    print("You ran away!")
  end
end
```